# Why a skype instance doesn't shut down?

Tags: 12.04, skype

I'm using 12.04 64 bits and Skype version 4.0.0.8 released yesterday ( http://blogs.skype.com/garage/2012/07/hotfix_for_multiple_skype_clie.html ).

The problem is : I'm using Skype normally. No problems with that. The problem happen when I try shut down Skype. Apparently works, but if I check( ps -aux on console ), the instance still alive.

So, If I shut down and start Skype again I receive one message error : "Another skype instance may exist".

Someone knows anything about it?

Comment: How are you shutting it down? Are you logging off before you do it? This might be considered a bug and can only be fixed by Skype, I am not sure about how to report bugs directly to Skype (that would make a good question!).

Comment: my skype on ubuntu 12.04 shuts down and cannot be restarted every time i am making a call and a popup notice is displayed.  who really believes that microsoft is going to fix linux bugs in skype?  HELLO ALICE, YOU ARE NOT IN KANSAS ANYMORE.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed this behaviour as well on my 12.04LTS and Skype version 2.2.0.35 Beta.
When you click on the orange circle with cross I get this behaviour.
When you use Ctrl+Q it closes correctly without leaving instance running in memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the directions provided for [Skype Logging and debugging feature](https://developer.skype.com/SkypeGarage/LogFile), to debug the issues in Skype process:

- Close Skype
- Create directory "Logs" under your Skype data directory (~/.Skype/)
- Restart Skype
- Log file (skype_yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss) will be created in ~/.Skype/Logs
- To turn off logging again, delete the "Logs" directory

You can then submit your bug report at [Skype Issue tracker](https://jira.skype.com). There is `Skype Client for Linux` option in the list. Fill the description and attach the debug and other (if any) log files you have been *tailing* (`tail -f ~/SomeLogFile`). And hope the issue get resolved in the next update. (-8