# How do I report a bug directly to Skype?

Tags: skype, bug-reporting

Skype supplies updated packages for Ubuntu via their website and via their [partner repository in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/skype).

How do I report a bug directly to the Skype team? Is the Launchpad packaging team the same that supplies the packages for the Skype website?

Lets say I have installed the latest version of Skype from their website and I stop fishy behavior, were do I report it?

ie: [`this question`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165203/why-a-skype-instance-doesnt-shut-down) is about the package downloaded directly from the Skype site, how do I report that as a bug?

Comment: What type of support/bugreporting are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: That might need to go to Skype directly... weren't they bought by Microsoft...?

Comment: yeah, but that is not the question here, the question is `where do I report it` and `is it the same team that packages it for launchpad?`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Bugs should be reported *directly* to Skype via their "public issue bug tracker" at https://jira.skype.com/
(requires a regular Skype login, obv)

If you haven't reported bugs before (even to Launchpad, etc), I would recommend reading their wiki page first, at:

http://developer.skype.com/SkypeGarage/ReportIssue

Comment: Unfortunately https://jira.skype.com/ doesn't appear to be up anymore, and http://dev.skype.com/issue-reporting-guide doesn't seem to have content anymore (it's blank, except for links to other developer topics).

Comment: Neither link worked.

Answer (score 4):

MS discontinued all bug reporting/ feature request webpages. All that's left is http://community.skype.com/

Comment: Do you have any references or announcements about that? They must do something, built-in error reporting, etc?

Comment: I wish I had, but no, I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Here is detailed instructions to file an Issue

https://developer.skype.com/SkypeGarage/ReportIssue

```
Reporting Issues

How to report an Issue

    Go to - https://jira.skype.com/
    Login to Jira
    Click on Create issue
    Choose appropriate project:
    - Skype Client for Linux for Linux client issues.
    - Skype Client for Mac for Mac client issues.
    - Skype Client for Windows for Windows client issues.
    Select appropriate issue type:
    - Bug - you have found that something in Skype is not working as you expect.
    - Improvement - you would like to see existing function improved.
    - New Feature - you would like to have new feature implemented in Skype.
    Click "Next"
    Fill in the fields:
        Summary - write a short summary of your issue.
        Description - write a longer description of the problem. Write what you expected to happen and what really happened. Write steps how to reproduce your problem and info are you able to reproduce it.
        Priority - assign a priority to your issue.
        Components - select a component in which describes best your issue.
        Affected versions - select version with what you encountered problem.
        Skype Version - detailed version number of Skype you are using for example 2.0.0.42.
        Operating System - select your operating system.
        OS Version - write here your exact OS Version.
        Attachment - Add a screen shot and log files of error or misbehaviour to the report.
    Click "Create" and your issue will be submitted to Skype.
```